Consider complex number $z$ such that $|z^2 + z + 1| = 4.$ Find the greatest value of the imaginary part of $z$.

Consider complex number $z$ such that $|z^2 + z + 1| = 4.$ Find the
greatest value of the imaginary part of $z$.

Since $z \neq 1$, I initially considered rewriting the equation as $|z^3 -1| = 4|z-1|$, but I couldn't proceed any further in this direction.
If I let $z = x + yi$, then we have $(x^2 - y^2 + x + 1)^2 + (2xy +y)^2 = 16$
Expanding the squares didn't seem like a working strategy as I was left with terms of various degrees for both $x$ and $y$ with no useful pattern. I hope to receive some hints. The problem is for us high school students with knowledge of single-variable calculus (if calculus is needed at all), so I'd appreciate approaches that do not involve techniques from multivariable calculus.
Thank you very much!

I would substitute $w=z+{1\over 2}.$ The imaginary part of $w$ is the same as for $z.$ The equation simplifies slightly to $|w^2+{3\over 4}|=4.$

@RyszardSzwarc That's a brilliant idea. Thank you very much!

$$z^2+z+1=\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}$$
Since we are only concerned with the imaginary part of $z$, without loss of generality, we may consider the shift $w = z +\frac{1}{2}$, and find the largest imaginary part of those $w$ with
$$\left|w^2+\frac{3}{4}\right|=4$$
Therefore $$|w|^2 \le 4 + \frac{3}{4} = \frac{19}{4} \\ \text{Im}(w)\le |w|\le \frac{\sqrt{19}}{2}$$
And when $w=\frac{\sqrt{19}}{2}i$ (equivalently $z=-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{19}}{2}i$), the equality can be achieved.

Thank you very much! On seeing Ryszard's comment, I initially thought of letting $w = x + yi$ and tried analyzing the discriminant, which looks very nice ($\Delta = 12y^2 + 64$) but is always greater than 0, so it doesn't help. Your comment came about and cleared up my confusion!

@ten_to_tenth Geometrically it's pretty clear that when the product of distance from $w$ to $\pm \sqrt{3}/2$ is fixed, in order to maximize $\text{Im}(w)$, $w$ must be purely imaginary. But algebraically it's always a good idea to keep working with complex numbers as a whole instead of real and imaginary parts, until we cannot.

@Justauser thank you very much for your elegant answer! My answer uses a bad idea.

@whatamidoing Oh, what am I doing? thank you. has been fixed by Raut. (Also in my comment above, it should be the distance from $w$ to $\pm \sqrt 3 i / 2$ ($i$ is missing).

@Justauser +1 Nice answer. I was about to post the essentially same answer. I discarded mine just after you posted it.

@Justauser Sorry that your comment went over my head, but could you please clarify why "in order to maximize Im(w), w must be purely imaginary"?

@ten_to_tenth it's a "vague" feeling, but not so different from the algebraic proof.  As the product of the distance is fixed, in order to maximize the imaginary part, you don't want to "waste" to move off the straight line formed by $\pm \sqrt 3 i / 2$, because if you do so, the real part will "use" some of the distances, which will further constrain the range of the imaginary parts. I'm sure this can be fully justified, but to do so, instead we might as well just follow the algebraic proof.

@Justauser Thank you!

Let $f(y):=y^4+(2x^2+2x-1)y^2+(x^2+x+1)^2-16$.
We want the maximum value of $y$ which satisfies $f(y)=0$ for some real number $x$.
Let $g(z):=z^2+(2x^2+2x-1)z+(x^2+x+1)^2-16$.
We want the maximum value of $z$ which is greater than or equal to $0$ and satisfies $g(z)=0$ for some real number $x$.
Solving $g(z)=0$, we get $$z=\frac{-2x^2-2x+1\pm\sqrt{(2x^2+2x-1)^2-4[(x^2+x+1)^2-16]}}{2}=\frac{-2x^2-2x+1\pm\sqrt{6(-2x^2-2x+1)+55}}{2}.$$
We want the maximum value of $-2x^2-2x+1$ which satisfies $6(-2x^2-2x+1)+55\geq 0$ and $\frac{-2x^2-2x+1+\sqrt{6(-2x^2-2x+1)+55}}{2}\geq 0$.
Let $h(x):=-2x^2-2x+1$.
Then, $h(x)=-2(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{2}$.
So, the maximum value of $h(x)$ is $\frac{3}{2}$ when $x=-\frac{1}{2}$.
When $x=-\frac{1}{2}$, $6(-2x^2-2x+1)+55=64\geq 0$ and $\frac{-2x^2-2x+1+\sqrt{6(-2x^2-2x+1)+55}}{2}=\frac{19}{4}\geq 0$ holds.
So, the maximum value of $y$ which satisfies $f(y)=0$ for some real number $x$ is $y=\sqrt{\frac{19}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{19}}{2}$.

Hi, thanks for your answer!

Your way is also fine, indeed from here $(x^2 - y^2 + x + 1)^2 + (2xy +y)^2 = 16$ by $x=u-\frac12$ we obtain
$$\left(u^2 - y^2 + \frac34\right)^2 + (2uy)^2 = 16 \iff y^4+y^2\left(2u^2-\frac32\right)+\left(u^4+\frac32u^2-\frac{247}{16}\right)=0$$
wich leads to
$$y^2(u) = -u^2+\frac34+\sqrt{16-u^2}$$
which is maximized at $u=0$ such that $y^2_{max}=\frac{19}4$.

Thank you very much!
